# Unity webgl porting to chrome web store

Tags: chrome-web-store, unity-webgl

I am looking for a simple guide how to port from Unity WebGL build to Chrome Web Store.
Nothing found on the web, but it seems to be possible for me, because of HTML5 technology on which both are based.

Please, share your knowledge here.